# How can I change the dates used in TFS 2010 SharePoint portal's burndown excel chart?

Tags: excel, tfs

We have a TFS 2010 project (MSF Agile v5.0 template) project, the SSRS reports for burndown allow us to specify start and end dates for the current iteration, but the project portals excel charts parts for burndown do not seem to have that option anywhere I can find it.

[image: An example Excel burndown chart with incorrect itteration dates]

Can anyone explain how I can configure the portal's excel burndown chart to have the begin and end dates **I want** rather than the defaults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the PivotTable filters to set the appropriate date range.  Try this:

- Open the Burndown Excel workbook.
- Click the dropdown on the Date field in the PivotTable
- Select Date Filters --> Between, and then enter the dates of your iteration.
- Once you've done that, the workbook should update to the date range you selected.  If the number of days changes, you'll also have to adjust each series on the chart to match the new date range.

  [image]